# haskell foldl with output

Tags: list, haskell

i am parsing a string for example "xxxxyzz", so if the char is "x" then i will need to do a output and make changes to the list at the same time. The code below is

```
import Data.Char
output l = zipWith (+) rr ll
            where
              out = foldl
                        ( \ (c,a) e ->
                               case c of
                                'x' -> chr c!!0 --output first element of the list
                                       ([1]++tail(c),a) ) -- add [1] to the c list
                        ([0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0])
              (ll,rr) = out l
```

Comment: To get started. Think of what type signature you need, then go and write your implementation

Comment: You may be interested in `foldM`, which is a left fold that includes a monadic operation (such as `IO`).

Comment: The body of the lambda does not make sense to me--is the case statement supposed to have an exhaustive set of cases? And in any event, c will be a list, and you are matching it against a char. Can you get the code to compile? And if not, post the error--I think that your problems run much deeper than the fold (you can use foldl with monadic operations--you just need to pay attention to type signatures).

Answer (score 1):

You can write (not recommended) some like

```
output'' :: String -> IO String
output'' = fmap reverse . foldM parseChar []
  where parseChar xs 'x' = putStrLn "'x' to upper" >> return ('X':xs)
        parseChar xs 'y' = putStrLn "'y' to 'W'"   >> return ('W':xs)
        parseChar xs  x  = putStrLn "no transform" >> return ( x :xs)
```

with output

```
*Main> output'' "xyz"
'x' to upper
'y' to 'W'
no transform
"XWz"
```

But, from [For a Few Monads More](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) (Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!)

You can write some like:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

output :: String -> Writer [String] String
output [] = return []
output (x:xs) = do
  xs' <- output xs
  x'  <- case x of
         'x' -> tell ["'x' to upper"] >> return 'X'
         'y' -> tell ["'y' to 'W'"]   >> return 'W'
         _   -> tell ["no transform"] >> return x
  return (x':xs')
```

using monads is more flexible and using Writer do your code pure (is pure and you have control about how process monadic context and data; not in direct IO `output''` function).

You can use `output` function into impure code as

```
main = do
  input <- getLine
  let (result, logging) = runWriter $ output input
  putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ result
  putStrLn $ unlines logging
```

a running output could be

```
*Main> main
hxdynx
Result: hXdWnX
'x' to upper
no transform
'y' to 'W'
no transform
'x' to upper
no transform
```

you can combine monad with monadic functions like "foldM", some like

```
output' :: String -> Writer [String] String
output' = fmap reverse . foldM parseChar []
  where parseChar xs 'x' = tell ["'x' to upper"] >> return ('X':xs)
        parseChar xs 'y' = tell ["'y' to 'W'"]   >> return ('W':xs)
        parseChar xs  x  = tell ["no transform"] >> return ( x :xs)
```

(log array are reversed)

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell you can't predict the order of execution without using monads. For starters you may want to try to do some testing in the `do` block of `main` and then rewrite it as a separate function.

You may want to familiarize yourself with the concept of IO in Haskell:
http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch7.html#x14-1420007